# TSQL generating update statement for table based on condition

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How to generate update statement on the whole table with some condition ? For example I have table

[image]

and I would like to specify date (for this example `'3/16/2016'`) and generate something like following Update

```
UPDATE TableName SET ColumnValue = 30 AND ModifiedDate = '2016-03-17' WHERE Id = 2
```

If there will be more changes after specified date, I would like to generate all the updates for these changes.

Is there some easy solution or I have to script all this by some customized `C#` script ?

Comment: We need more details to answer this question. Like what rows you want to update, from where do you get the data, stuff like that.

Comment: I need to generate update statements for the rows that was changed after some date. (to create an export file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to generate update statements, you could do something like this:

```
declare @afterDate date = '20160316';

select update_statements = 'update table t set columnvalue = '
       +convert(varchar(10),columnvalue)
       +', modifieddate = '''
       +replace(convert(varchar(10),modifieddate,120),'-','')+''''
       +' where id = '+convert(varchar(10),id)+';'
from t
where modifieddate > @afterdate;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/MZQ68677

returns:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                              update_statements                               |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| update table t set columnvalue = 30, modifieddate = '20160317' where id = 2; |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have 2 identical tables and need to update one of the tables based on changes happed after a particular timestamp (@Date) in another table then you can use below query.

```
UPDATE T1
SET T1.ColumnValue=T2.ColumnValue,T1.ModifiedDate=T2.ModifiedDate
FROM Table1 T1 inner join Table2 T2 on T1.ID=T2.ID
WHERE T2.ModifiedDate>=@Date
```

Comment: thank you but that is not my scenario, I need to have the update statements as an export file.

Comment: In that case you can use SQL triggers on that table to log the update statements for every data modifications.

Comment: can you please be more specific ?

Answer (score 0):

This gives the trigger to track all the updates for a table. Based on table structure you can add required columns in the tracking table.

```
CREATE TABLE EMP(ID int, NAME VARCHAR(20), SALARY MONEY)
CREATE TABLE TrackUpdate (Id int identity, updatestmt varchar(500), DateCreated datetime)
GO
INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES
(1, 'A', 10),(2, 'E',40 ),(3,'B',5),(4,'F',40),(5,'I',50)
GO
 ALTER TRIGGER TR_EMP ON EMP
 INSTEAD OF UPDATE
 AS
 BEGIN
     declare @Name varchar(10)
     declare @Salary MONEY
     SELECT @Name=Name,@Salary=Salary FROM inserted
     insert into TrackUpdate values ('update Emp SET E.Name='''+@Name+''', '+'E.Salary='+CAST(@Salary as varchar(20)),getdate())
     update E SET E.Name=I.Name, E.Salary=I.Salary
     FROM EMP E inner join inserted I on I.ID=E.ID 
 END
update EMP set Name='D' where ID=4
select updatestmt  from TrackUpdate 
--drop table EMP
--drop table TrackUpdate
```